# Having An Issue With Fontawesome icons returning as boxes

Tags: javascript, css

So, Im trying to set up a hamburger menu setup where the icons appears when I shrink my browser down to a mobile size, and when the hamburger icon is clicked, its replaced with an X icon until I click it again to close the mobile menu. My issue is that even with the CDN appropriately placed in my index.html file, my icons are appearing as boxes. I've tried importing the library to my navbar page in a variety of different ways, but haven't been able to find out what exactly Ive done wrong. I did manage to get the faMonsterTruck icon to load, but how I got this icon to work is not working in my click event. My code for my navbar.js page looks as such:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./navbar.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { faTruckMonster } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

function Navbar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [button, setButton] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

  const showButton = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 960) {
      setButton(false);
    } else {
      setButton(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    showButton();
  }, []);

  window.addEventListener("resize", showButton);

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="navbar-container">
          <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
            EPC
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTruckMonster} />
          </Link>
          <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className={click ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"} />
          </div>
          <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to="/" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/zero" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Year 0
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to="/one" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Year 1
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to="/two" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Year 2
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to="/three" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Year 3
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to="/four" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Year 4
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

In case it's difficult to locate where I need help exactly, the click event code I referenced is this snippet here:

```
<div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className={click ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"} />
          </div>
          <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
            <li className="nav-item">
```

I know that I have some useless code in there for button calls. Im cleaning up the page as I go, as my plans for how I want my page to appear have changed a couple times.